# Assign a big number to unsigned int in C

Tags: c, unsigned-integer

I am trying to assign a number to unsigned int, but it results in an error.
I thought as long as the number is between 0 and 2^32, it should work.
Here is my code.

```
unsigned int number = 4026658824;
```

However, I get this error.

> error: constant promoted according to the 1999 ISO C standard

Comment: `unsigned int` is in range [0, 2^32-1].

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych Yeah so what? The problem isn't related to unsigned int, but to the rules for which type the compiler picks for an integer constant. A better compiler warning would have been: "warning: implicit conversion from long int to unsigned int".

Comment: @Lundin > " I thought as long as the number is between 0 and 2^32". I just pointed that out, maybe OP would try to strore there 2^32 and encounter an overflow.

Comment: Which compilation options are you using with which compiler?  It looks like they're fussy (which is good!).  Basically, add a U to the end of the number and you should be OK.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych `2^32 = 4.29*10^9`. The OP is trying to store a smaller number than that, `4.03*10^9`.

Comment: @Lundin - Yes, and it's even smaller than `2^32 - 1`, but the OP had a misconception about the range of 32 bit unsigned integers, and Yuriy pointed that out. Nothing wrong with that so long as it is a comment and not an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Lundin I can see that, thanks. That's why I answered you previously "would try" meaning the future. I am sorry for my English if that is a reason.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych C does not specify "`unsigned int` is in range [0, 2^32-1]", although that is commonly implmented.  `unsigned` is specified to have a range of _at least_ [0-65535].

Comment: Right. I forgot it was actually 2^32 - 1.. 
It worked when I put "u" at the end of the number! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Type of decimal constant depends on the type in which it can be represented, per [6.4.4.1 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1):

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

(See the table in the link for how C language says the *actual* type of integer constants is deduced).

Typically a signed int can't represent the value `4026658824`. So, `4026658824` probably has type `long int` or `long long int` on your system. If `unsigned int` can be represent `4026658824` then this is fine but your compiler is being cautious.

You could use `u` or `U` suffix or cast it to `unsigned int`. The suffix `u` may not work if the integer constant has bigger value. For example, if `17179869184u` can't be represented by `unsigned int` then its type may be `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int` and you may still get diagnostics about it.

Comment: I wish there was a way to make sure the type of the variable is identical to the type of the literal. GCC has `typeof` that you can wrap in a macro, but it's non-standard :(.

Comment: @StoryTeller, better to choose the target type appropriately for the needs of your program, and to be sure to express the constant appropriately for the desired type.  The standard has specific [rules for how the type of an integer constant is determined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5).

Comment: @StoryTeller, and if the needs of the program are determined by the value of the constant, then C has explicit-width and minimum-width types.  For example, one might declare the variable as `uint_least32_t` (from `stdint.h`).  That does not change the need to express constants in a appropriate form.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - The rules don't protect you when you move to a platform where the sizes shift (thought unlikely today). Like P.P. pointed out, simply sticking a `u` there won't protect you either. **Deducing** the type correctly when the constant has meaning will make for more portable code (Well standard width integers not withstanding, as you added in your second comment, while I was typing this one).

Comment: @StoryTeller Everything is possible in C if you throw enough evil macros on it!!! This isn't really a serious suggestion, but... the macro `#define UINT_DECLARE_INIT(name, bits, value) uint ## bits ##_t name = UINT ## bits ## _C (value)` used as `UINT_DECLARE_INIT(hello, 32, 4123456789);` will expand to `uint32_t hello = UINT32_C(4123456789);` which in turn expands to `uint32_t hello = (4123456789U);`. The variable type and the literal are now safely matched. Though of course it might just be wiser to use `UINT32_C` manually :)

Comment: @Lundin - I am both intrigued and horrified by what you just wrote. And I now also understand why the standard makes  `uint_leastN_t` integers a required typedef :)

Comment: @StoryTeller The serious solution, in my opinion, would be to be careful with types as you go, always considering which type an integer constant will get. And then run static analysis on the code afterwards. If there's something static analysers is good at, it is whining about implicit integer conversions. For example any MISRA-C checker would have whined about the original code, if only to tell you to use an `u` suffix.

Comment: @StoryTeller, supposing that you declare the type so that it is certain to be wide enough (e.g. by using an appropriate one of the `uint_leastN_t` types), appending a `U` to the value of the initialization constant is entirely sufficient to handle this case.  The resulting constant may be narrower than the type, but its value is sure to be representable in the type.  The compiler should not complain.

Comment: @neko_studies_prog Detail: appending a suffix `u` is not casting.  It is just the syntax for an _integer constant_  that insures it will be a  `unsigned`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, if you want a variable to definitely be a certain number of bits, use [Fixed-width integer types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_variable_types_and_declarations#Fixed-width_integer_types). Doing embedded work we have to be careful of this (CPU may only be 8 or 16-bit) so pretty much always use them for everything.

Comment: Although good advise, this doesn't really answer the question. `uint32_t number = 4026658824;` would have given the very same diagnostic. To dodge the diagnostic by using stdint types, you would have to write `uint32_t number = UINT32_C(4026658824);`

Comment: Hence "In **addition to** the answers above..."