# Size of a float variable and compilation

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I'm struggling to understand the behavior of `gcc` in this. The size of a float is of 4 bytes for my architecture. But I can still store a 8 bytes real value in a float, and my compiler says nothing about it.

For example I have :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    float someFloatNumb = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    printf("%i\n", sizeof(someFloatNumb));
    printf("%f\n", someFloatNumb);
    printf("%i\n", sizeof(281474976710656));

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the compiler to insult me, or displaying a disclaimer of some sort, because I shouldn't be able to something like that, at least I think it's kind of twisted wizardry.

The program simply run :

```
4
281474976710656.000000
8
```

So, if I print the size of `someFloatNumb`, I get 4 bytes, which is expected. But the affected value isn't, as seen just below.

So I have a few questions:

- Does sizeof(variable) simply get the variable type and return sizeof(type), which in this case would explain the result?
- Does/Can gcc grow the capacity of a type? (managing multiple variables behind the curtains to allow us that sort of things)

Comment: `sizeof(281474976710656)` is just giving you `sizeof(int)`

Comment: *I can still store a 8 bytes real value in a float*  You can?  How?  All you can store is the floating-point *representation* of that 8-byte value.  And you lose a lot of information in the conversion.

Comment: @cleblanc this is not necessary true, could be sizeof(long) as well sizeof(long long)

Comment: You cast the value ``0xFFFFFFFFFFFF`` to a float, the compiler converts this, it does not ``reinterpret_cast`` the variable. Do you notice, that ``0xFFFFFFFFFFFF`` is not an even number as its representation as a float ``281474976710656.000000`` is, this is caused by the mantissa, which cannot store the least significant bits of the integer constant.

Comment: If a compiler insulted me, I would remove it from my system. <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> Does sizeof(variable) simply get the variable type and return sizeof(type), which in this case would explain the result ?

Except for [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand. So yes, all it cares is the type. So `sizeof(someFloatNumb)` is 4 which is equivalent to `sizeof(float)`. This explains `printf("%i\n", sizeof(someFloatNumb));`.

2)

> [..] But I can still store a 8 bytes real value in a float, and my compiler says nothing about it.
>   Does/Can gcc grow the capacity of a type ? (managing multiple variables behind the curtains to allow us that sort of things)

No. Capacity doesn't grow. You simply misunderstood how floats are represented/stored. `sizeof(float)` being 4 doesn't mean
it can't store more than 2^32 (assuming 1 byte == 8 bits). See [Floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Internal_representation).
What the maximum value of a `float` can represent is defined by the constant `FLT_MAX` (see `<float.h>`). `sizeof(someFloatNumb)` simply yields how many bytes the object (`someFloatNumb`) takes up in memory which isn't necessarily equal to the *range* of values it can represent.
This explains why `printf("%f\n", someFloatNumb);` prints the value as expected (and there's no automatic "capacity growth").

3)

> printf("%i\n", sizeof(281474976710656));

This is slightly more involved. As said before in (1), `sizeof` only cares about the type here. But the type of `281474976710656` is not necessarily `int`.
The C standard defines the *type* of integer constants according to the smallest type that can represent the value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115024/1275169 for an explanation.

On my system `281474976710656` can't be represented in an `int` and it's stored in a `long int` which is likely to be case on your system as well. So what you see is essentially equivalent to `sizeof(long)`.

There's no portable way to determine the *type* of integer constants. But since you are using `gcc`, you could use a little trick with `typeof`:

```
typeof(281474976710656) x;
printf("%s", x); /* deliberately using '%s' to generate warning from gcc. */
```

generates:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
>        printf("%s", x);

---

P.S: `sizeof` results a `size_t` for which the correct format specifier is `%zu`. So that's what you should be using in your 1st and 3rd printf statements.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't store "8 bytes" of data, that value gets converted to an integer by the compiler, then converted to a `float` for assignment:

```
float someFloatNumb = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF; // 6 bytes of data
```

Since `float` can represent large values, this isn't a big deal, but you will lose a lot of precision if you're only using 32-bit floats. Notice there's a slight but important difference here:

```
float value = 281474976710656.000000;
int value   = 281474976710655;
```

This is because `float` becomes an approximation when it runs out of precision.

Capacities don't "grow" for standard C types. You'll have to use a ["bignum" library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) for that.

Comment: A float doesn't 'run out' of precision.

Comment: @nicomp It has limits on what it can represent depending on how many bits are available for the significant digits. Assuming this is a [32-bit IEEE floating point value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) then it's a fluke the approximation is so close to the intended value, and then only because it's all 1 bits in the original.

Comment: I think you want to say that when converting from a base 10 number to a base 2 number for storage in a float type you may run out of precision before the conversion is complete.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can still store a 8 bytes real value in a float, and my compiler
>   says nothing about it.

That's not what's happening.

```
float someFloatNumb = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

`0xFFFFFFFFFFFF` is an integer constant. Its value, expressed in decimal, is `281474976710655`, and its type is *probably* either `long` or `long long`. (Incidentally, that value can be stored in 48 bits, but most systems don't have a 48-bit integer type, so it will probably be stored in 64 bits, of which the high-order 16 bits will be zero.)

When you use an expression of one numeric type to initialize an object of a different numeric type, the value is *converted*. This conversion doesn't depend on the size of the source expression, only on its numeric value. For an integer-to-float conversion, the result is the closest representation to the integer value. There may be some loss of precision (and in this case, there is). Some compilers may have options to warn about loss of precision, but the conversion is perfectly valid so you probably won't get a warning by default.

Here's a small program to illustrate what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    long long ll = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    float f      = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    printf("ll = %lld\n", ll);
    printf("f  = %f\n", f);
}
```

The output on my system is:

```
ll = 281474976710655
f  = 281474976710656.000000
```

As you can see, the conversion has lost some precision. `281474976710656` is an exact power of two, and floating-point types generally can represent those exactly. There's a very small difference between the two values because you chose an integer value that's very close to one that can be represented exactly.  If I change the value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    long long ll = 0xEEEEEEEEEEEE;
    float f      = 0xEEEEEEEEEEEE;
    printf("ll = %lld\n", ll);
    printf("f  = %f\n", f);
}
```

the apparent loss of precision is much larger:

```
ll = 262709978263278
f  = 262709979381760.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

0xFFFFFFFFFFFF == 281474976710655

If you init a float with that value, it will end up being
0xFFFFFFFFFFFF +1 == 0x1000000000000 == 281474976710656 == 1<<48

That fits easily in a 4byte float, simple mantisse, small exponent.
It does however NOT store the correct value (one lower) because that IS hard to store in a float.

Note that the " +1" does not imply incrementation. It ends up one higher because the representation can only get as close as off-by-one to the attempted value. You may consider that "rounding up to the next power of 2 mutliplied by whatever the mantisse can store". Mantisse, by the way, usually is interpreted as a fraction between 0 and 1.
Getting closer would indeed require the 48 bits of your initialisation in the mantisse; plus whatever number of bits would be used to store the exponent; and maybe a few more for other details.

Comment: 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF +1 == 0x1 0000 0000 0000, you omitted a zero in your equation.

Comment: @nicomp True, fixed. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I have a question, why would the value be incremented when a float is initialized with this value ?

Comment: It is not incremented, it ends up one higher because the representation can only get as close as off-by-one to the attempted value.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the value printed... `0xFFFF...FFFF` is an odd value, but the value printed in your example is even.  You are feeding the `float` variable with an `int` value that is converted to `float`.  The conversion is loosing precision, as expected by the value used, which doesn't fit in the 23 bits reserved to the target variable mantissa.  And finally you get an approximation with is the value `0x1000000....0000` (the next value, which is the closest value to the one you used, as posted @Yunnosch in his answer)