# Why can't I print an unsigned int with printf in C?

Tags: c, gcc, printf, long-integer, unsigned-integer

For a school project, I'm trying to re-create the `printf` function of the `stdio.h` library in C.

I'm currently working on getting the `unsigned int` printing part working, but for some reason, why I try the real `printf` to print an unsigned int, it gives me a warning (which is considered as an error in my school). Could you someone explain me why?

Here is the code line I have used: `printf("%u\n", 4294967295);`. And here is the error I'm gettting:

```
main.c:18:17: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
        printf("%u\n", 4294967295);
                ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~
                %ld
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: The warning is quite clear. What part do you not understand?

Comment: You must write `4294967295U`, not `4294967295`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The *type* of integer constants isn't fixed and depends on [what type can actually represent that value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42115024/1275169).

Comment: Just undeleted it @bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All integer constants such as `4294967295` have a type, just like declared variables. The C compiler assigns a type to such a constant based on various intricate rules. A simplified explanation is that these rules basically boil down to:

- "Does it fit in an `int`? If so, make it `int`."
- "Otherwise does it fit in a `long`?" ... and so on.

Note that these default types are signed types.

On a 32 bit computer with 32 bit int, the largest number you can store in an `int` is 2^31 - 1 = `2147483647`. `4294967295` is larger than that, so the compiler has to store it in a `long`. Hence the warning.

Since `4294967295` would have fit in an `unsigned int`, so you could fix the code by simply forcing the compiler to treat the integer constant as unsigned: `4294967295u`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of an integer literal is taken as the first type in the list in the standard that fits. The list for literals without the any suffix is `int`, `long int`, `long long int`/`unsigned long int`. As 4294967295 doesn't fit in `int`, it'll be `long` if `long` is a type wider than 32-bit (which is the case on your platform). To get an `unsigned int` literal you need to use the `U` suffix

> ## [The type of integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant)
>
> The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which *integer-suffix* was used.
>
> **Types allowed for integer constants:**
>
> - no suffix
>
>   - decimal bases:
>
>     - int
>     - long int
>     - unsigned long int (until C99)
>     - long long int (since C99)
>   - other bases:
>
>     - int
>     - unsigned int
>     - long int
>     - unsigned long int
>     - long long int (since C99)
>     - unsigned long long int (since C99)
> - ...
>
> If the value of the integer constant is too big to fit in any of the types allowed by suffix/base combination and the compiler supports extended integer types (such as `__int128`), the constant may be given the extended integer type; otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: This is kind of a C++ answer. C does not have binary base and in case a number does not fit in an extended integer type, it has no type - it is not "ill-formed", there's nothing called ill-formed in C.

Comment: @Lundin C23 has binary integer literal https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant

Comment: That remains to be seen, that standard is still in development.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are trying to print an unsigned int, but the value you passed in the `printf("%u\n", 4294967295)` is of type long. So you can try changing the datatype to `unsigned long int`